# oracle conditional where clause with filter

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have to use a conditional where clause like below one, what is the working version of this clause?

```
AND CASE WHEN b.kurum_turu = 1 
         THEN u.kod  in ('1125', '2975', '1127', '4460', '1128', '1126')  
    ELSE u.kod  in ('1125', '2975')                 
END
```

Comment: You're uisng this in a query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you want this for a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
(
  b.kurum_turu = 1
  AND u.kod  in ('1125', '2975', '1127', '4460', '1128', '1126')
)
OR
(
  u.kod  in ('1125', '2975') 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite that as

```
...
WHERE
    (
        (b.kurum_turu = 1 AND u.kod in ('1125', '2975', '1127', '4460', '1128', '1126'))
        OR
        ((b.kurum_turu IS NULL OR b.kurum_turu != 1) AND u.kod in ('1125', '2975'))
    )
```

Comment: +1, but you'd possibly want to add something for kurum_turu being null

Comment: Given the first condition, `(b.kurum_turu IS NULL OR b.kurum_turu != 1)` is unnecessary in the second

Answer (score 2):

i think this is what you need..

```
 where ...AND CASE WHEN b.kurum_turu = 1 
         and u.kod  in ('1125', '2975', '1127', '4460', '1128', '1126') then 1  
         when  u.kod  in ('1125', '2975') then 1
     else 0      
END=1
```

Comment: its not good to write it this way (even though it's possible). you'd negate any index possibility with this approach. bluefeet's appraoch above is more index friendly.

Comment: Got it @DazzaL , you were saying like in this type of query,table will anyway go for full scan even in presence of  index...
correct me if i am wrong..

Answer (score 0):

My aproach is this:

```
 AND 1 = CASE
         WHEN  b.kurum_turu = 1 AND u.kod  in ('1125', '2975', '1127', '4460', '1128', '1126') THEN 1 ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform a list of strings by using `CONNECT BY` in order to obtain a conditional `IN` statement.

This solution is usefull if you have serveral conditionals since you can write the `IN` clause as a single expression without any other AND,  OR restrictions.

```
WHERE u.kod IN 
(
  SELECT rowdata FROM
  ( WITH DATA AS 
    (SELECT CASE WHEN b.kurum_turu = 1 THEN '1125, 2975, 1127, 4460, 1128, 1126' ELSE '1125, 2975' END rowdata FROM dual )
    SELECT trim(regexp_substr(rowdata, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) rowdata FROM DATA CONNECT BY instr(rowdata, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
  )
)
```

This comes with the drawback that the transformation of the comma separated values to data rows is a bit complex ... but you can extract this complex part into a well named function in order to hide this complexity.