# Case expression Issue

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run this below select query

```
select c.customer_id ,
c.customer_name,
c.city

from
customers c
where 
case when c.customer_name = 'Sai' then c.city is null
and c.city!=null
```

Which is resulting in

ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 47

Can you please let me know how to fix this error ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [oracle conditional where clause with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951711/oracle-conditional-where-clause-with-filter)

Comment: Do not use `case` for conditional filtering (since Oracle doesn't have boolean data type). As long as you want to return `true` based on some condition, you may combine these conditions with simple logical operators: `and` or `or`. It is more readable and understandable by the query optimizer

Answer (score 1):

`!= NULL` will never be true and the `CASE` expression does not have an `END`.

To fix it , you can just use `AND` and `OR`:

```sql
select c.customer_id ,
       c.customer_name,
       c.city
from   customers c
where  ( c.customer_name = 'Sai' AND c.city IS NULL )
OR     ( ( c.customer_name != 'Sai' OR c.customer_name IS NULL )
       AND c.city IS NOT NULL )
```

If you must use a `CASE` expression then the expression in the `THEN`/`ELSE` clauses must be a value (and not a comparison) so you need to put the comparison outside of the `CASE` expression:

```sql
select c.customer_id ,
       c.customer_name,
       c.city
from   customers c
WHERE  CASE
       WHEN c.customer_name = 'Sai' AND c.city IS NULL
       THEN 1
       WHEN ( c.customer_name != 'Sai' OR c.customer_name IS NULL )
            AND c.city IS NOT NULL
       THEN 1
       END = 1
```

Comment: Thank You , I cannot change the query , I need to do it with Case statment only

Comment: any specific reason why case is not working here ?? plz let me know

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you're trying to do in your where clause?

`where case when c.customer_name = 'Sai' then c.city is null and c.city!=null`

Do you want the city to show null when the customer name is 'Sai'?
If so -

```
select c.customer_id ,
c.customer_name,
case when c.customer_name = 'Sai' then null else c.city end as city
from customers c
where c.city is not null
```

Comment: I'm not commenting on whether this query returns desired result or not (I'll leave it to the OP), but - `!= null` is wrong; nothing is equal (or not equal) to NULL. It is `is not null` you should use instead.

Comment: You're right. column is not null. My bad. Editing the post